# WKWebView: Is it possible to preload multiple URLs?

Tags: ios, swift, url, preload, wkwebview

Just migrated an app over to `WKWebView` and was wondering if there is any possible way to 'preload' multiple URLs, but only display one at a time?

I have a list of 5 URLs. I already know that I will be shown at some point in time, and I want to speed up the experience by pre-loading these for use in a single `WKWebView`.

Comment: Just wondering if these are your own web data or generic web pages (e.g., user specified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up just using NSURLCache and preloading all URLs using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection. Then whenever I load a url into WKWebView it uses the cached requests per my cache policy.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail as to how you achieved this using the 'load' method? The URLRequests don't seem to cache (maybe it depends on the response headers?).

Answer (score 2):

A relatively straight-forward way to do this is to create five `NSData` objects (asynchronoulsly), each initialized using the known urls. When you need to display one of them, you can convert the `NSData` to a string, and then call `WKWebView`'s `loadHTMLString` function to change the displayed page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also preload five different `WKWebView` instances and swap them in/out when you need a specific URL. This depends on your UI and interaction of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLCache

Here is the code

**Swift**

```
// Create URLRequest
    var request: URLRequest? = nil
    if let url = URL(string: "YOUR_URL") {
        request = URLRequest(url: url)
    }
    
    // Check the cache.
    var cachedResponse: CachedURLResponse? = nil
    if let request = request {
        cachedResponse = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: request)
    }
    print(cachedResponse != nil ? "Cached response found!" : "No cached response found.")
   // Load the cache
    do {
        if let request = request {
            try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returning: nil)
        }
    } catch {
    }
```

**Obj-C**

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL"]];

    // Check the cache.
    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    NSLog(cachedResponse ? @"Cached response found!" : @"No cached response found.");
    //Load cache
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
```